# Protractor Error first time - Jasmine spec timed out. Resseting WebDriver Control Flow

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor

Today I woke up and tried to run an `E2E` test using protractor as always and an error message show up:

> 'Jasmine spec timed out. Resseting WebDriver Control Flow'.

I want to point out that **this never happened before using same specs as always**. It does not make any sense to me.
Any thoughts? let me share my config:

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

var today = new Date(),
timeStamp = today.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + today.getDate() + '-' + today.getFullYear() + '-' + today.getHours() + 'h-' + today.getMinutes() + 'm';

var reporter = new HtmlReporter({
baseDirectory: '../test_out/e2e',
docTitle: 'Protractor Reporter',
docName: 'protractor-tests-report-' + timeStamp + '.html',
takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: false
});

exports.config = {

"allScriptsTimeout": 15000,

seleniumPort: 4444,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

// Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [
        '--disable-extensions'
        ]
    }
},

//A base URL for your application under test.
//Calls to protractor.get() with relative paths will be prepended with this.
//baseUrl: 'http://localhost/',
baseUrl: 'https://federation-sts-stage.accenture.com/adfs/ls?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2frecruitmentdocuments.ciostage.accenture.com%2f&wctx=rm%3d1%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252f&wct=2016-03-09T13%3a48%3a44Z&RedirectToIdentityProvider=urn%3afederation%3aaccenture%3astage',

frameworks: [
    'jasmine',
    'jasmine-matchers'
],

//An array of file patterns that point to your spec files.
//Patterns are relative to the current working directory when Protractor is started up.
specs: [
    //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/*.scenario.js"
    "../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/login.scenario.js",
    "../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/assignTask.scenario.js"
    //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/cancelTask.scenario.js",
    //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/search.scenario.js",
    //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/uploadDocument.scenario.js",
    //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/openDocument.scenario.js"
     //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/createOffer.scenario.js",
     //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/shareLink.scenario.js"
     //"../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/createOPR.scenario.js"
],

//Separate your tests in various test suites: 
//protractor protractor.conf.js --suite homepage
suites: {
    login: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/login.scenario.js',
    assignTask: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/assignTask.scenario.js'        
    //cancelTask: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/cancelTask.scenario.js',
    //search: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/search.scenario.js',
    //uploadDocument: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/uploadDocument.scenario.js',
    //openDocument: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/openDocument.scenario.js'
    //createOffer: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/createOffer.scenario.js',
    //shareLink: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/shareLink.scenario.js'
    //createOPR: '../../../../../ng-app/test/javascript/e2e/**/createOPR.scenario.js'
},

onPrepare: function () {
    //Set window size before starting the tests
    //browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(320, 568);
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

    var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        displayStacktrace: 'all',     // display stacktrace for each failed assertion, values: (all|specs|summary|none)
        displayFailuresSummary: true, // display summary of all failures after execution
        displayPendingSummary: true,  // display summary of all pending specs after execution
        displaySuccessfulSpec: true,  // display each successful spec
        displayFailedSpec: true,      // display each failed spec
        displayPendingSpec: false,    // display each pending spec
        displaySpecDuration: true,   // display each spec duration
        displaySuiteNumber: false,    // display each suite number (hierarchical)
        colors: {
            success: 'green',
            failure: 'red',
            pending: 'yellow'
        },
        prefixes: {
            success: '✓ ',
            failure: '✗ ',
            pending: '* '
        },
        customProcessors: []
    }));

    //// Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screnshots`: 
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
},



// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,                   //function to call before the driver quits
    showColors: true,                   //provide colored output during spec runs
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    isVerbose: true,                    //provide verbose output during spec runs
    includeStackTrace: true           //include a stack trace on errors
},
};
```

Comment: Try to increase your jasmine defaultTimeoutInterval: 2*60*1000, Something may change from Dev side. This error will come when It block will take time to execute & it went beyond defined time which is 60 sec in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your `allScriptsTimeout` is set to 15 seconds, and your `jasmine defaultTimeoutInterval` is set to 60 seconds. This means that if some async call takes longer than 15 seconds, or if an 'it' statement is running for longer than 60 seconds, jasmine will kill the test and throw this error message `Jasmine spec timed out`.

Either your application has changed such that your test is legitimately running slower than it used to (increase the timeout intervals to make the tests pass again, or address the performance of the application), or the test is hanging somewhere and getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

When we encounter the problem that a test suddenly stops working, it's often a mismatch between chrome versions & chromedriver. Chrome does automatic updates, it's webdriver doesn't by default.

## Checking the driver version

You can check by finding your chromedriver executable and opening it, that should display a version.

**See** [Chrome driver version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M978I.png)

Now make sure to check on [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) if your current version of chromedriver works with your chrome version. If it does not:

## Updating chromedriver

You may simply overwrite the chromedriver executable with the correct version.

the chromedriver can stay auto updated if you use the webdriver manager.
[This NPM package will auto update the needed drivers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager)